# Как записать в переменную высоту элемента

Tags: javascript

Как записать в переменную высоту элемента?

```
    var el = document.getElementById("id").style.width
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью директив `offsetHeight` и `offsetWidth`. Пример:

```
var el = document.getElementById("id").offsetHeight
```

Comment: Только надо учесть, что если высота для элемента не будет указана явно (напр., в CSS), то в разных браузерах у вас будут получены абсолютно разные значения. [Потестируйте код](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/aPLvu/6/)